# How set relative path in driver.get() method in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

In Selenium I can navigate to a URL using  driver.get(DesireURL) method. 
If  I have to navigate to a local HTML file I can use

```
driver.get("C://what ever the location of my file");
```

But if my HTML file located to in my project resource directory like resources/HTML/file.html.

I am using this code in Ubuntu and windows so a don't use absolute path.
How can I browse that file like driver.get(“resources/HTML/file.html”)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly create a AppConstant class where all the constant resources path are specified.

```
 /*
 * used to get the path of necessary resources 
 */
  public class AppConstant {

  // prevents instantiation
  private AppConstant () { 

 } 

  public static final String CURRENT_DIR = System.getProperty("user.dir");
  public static final String APP_RESOURCE = CURRENT_DIR+"/resources/";  
 }
```

Then use the resource path as follows

```
 driver.get("file:"+AppConstant.APP_RESOURCE+"HTML/file.html");
```

**EDIT:**  You can also verify by using this if you do not want to create another class

```
String htmlLocation = "file:"+System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/resources/HTML/Table.html";
driver.get(htmlLocation);
```

Comment: @Torikul Alam please use the above code. and let me know the result.

Comment: User wants to put the html resources under the project resource directory. So its better to create a App constant class. So that all constants are there.

Comment: To get the projects current directory the code is --> System.getProperty("user.dir")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.get("file:///C://what ever the location of my file");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file at any location you can use like this, simply use `file:///C:/Sankalp/test.html` address in `get("")`method

Try sample code:

```
public class Hello {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Users/sankalp.gupta/Desktop/JAVASEL/geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("file:///C:/Sankalp/test.html");  //replace it with your path
    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
}

}
```